# ZXing Result.getRawBytes(), what exactly is it?

Tags: java, android, zxing

I'm working with the zxing QR code APIs, and I'm trying to extract binary data from a QR code on an android device. However, on android, Result.getResultMetadata() isn't passed through to me through the Intent, so I tried to use Result.getRawBytes() to retrieve my byte array. However, getRawBytes() does not seem to return the same thing.

What exactly is Result.getRawBytes() and does anyone know how to extract byte arrays from zxing QR codes properly?

Thanks

Comment: Use CharsetEncoder/Decoder. `getRawBytes()` will return whatever is in QR code as an array of bytes. It's up to you to decode it properly. I think...

Comment: by "what is in the qr code" do you mean a 2d array of booleans or the raw byte data of the decode result? if it's the latter, then shouldn't getRawBytes be returning exactly what I put into the encode function of the QR code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what i think you want is the raw, decoded data in a byte array. The intent source that zxing gives you is missing the metadata, but it's still being sent to the intent filter.

In parseActivityResult inside of IntentIntegrator.java, you can add:

```
byte[] dataBytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra("SCAN_RESULT_BYTE_SEGMENTS_0");
return new IntentResult(contents,
                        formatName,
                        rawBytes,
                        orientation,
                        errorCorrectionLevel,
                        dataBytes);
```

I modified the IntentResult class to be able to take this extra piece:

```
private final byte[] dataBytes;

IntentResult() {
    this(null, null, null, null, null, null);
}

IntentResult(String contents,
           String formatName,
           byte[] rawBytes,
           Integer orientation,
           String errorCorrectionLevel,
           byte[] dataBytes) {
    this.contents = contents;
    this.formatName = formatName;
    this.rawBytes = rawBytes;
    this.orientation = orientation;
    this.errorCorrectionLevel = errorCorrectionLevel;
    this.dataBytes = dataBytes;
}


/**
* @return raw content of barcode in bytes
*/

public byte [] getDataBytes() {
  return dataBytes;
}
```

This byte array stores the first array of the metadata, AKA the raw contents of your data in bytes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Also note that "SCAN_RESULT_BYTE_SEGMENTS_0" will only give the first byte segment ; you also have to examine "SCAN_RESULT_BYTE_SEGMENTS_1", "SCAN_RESULT_BYTE_SEGMENTS_2" etc. if there is more data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not start with the [javadoc](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/index.html)?

It is the raw codewords in the QR code. It is not the individual parsed byte segments.

Comment: It moved a long time ago to https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/index.html - I'll edit the answer.