# Output barcode control codes using ZXing?

Tags: android, zxing, gs1-128, gs1-ai-syntax

Without changing any *ZXing source* code, is there a way to output control codes in a barcode using ZXing on Android?

*Edit: The reason that I don't want to edit source code is because I would like to use the ["scan via intent"](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) process.  If I have to edit source, then I'll have to embed the entire project into my project instead.*

For instance, I have a GS1-128 barcode that currently outputs text `21417341123`.  I would instead like to see something like `[Start C][FNC1]21417341123[Stop]`.

If I can get the raw data from the scan, that would also be OK.  But the "rawBytes" value is only for the data (21417341123 portion) and doesn't include the control codes.  I saw the question [ZXing Result.getRawBytes(), what exactly is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368684/zxing-result-getrawbytes-what-exactly-is-it), but the solution to use `getByteArrayExtra("SCAN_RESULT_BYTE_SEGMENTS_0");` returns `null`.

If it is not possible to do this without changing code, then I will need to modify the ZXing source.  I am just trying to see if I can do what I want without modifying source.

Comment: Did I do something wrong?  I have a close vote and a -1.  Edit: it appears that it got an "off topic" close vote.  I don't think this is off topic.  on the ZXing website it specifically says to post questions here.  Also, this is related to programming per http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the Barcode Scanner app itself supports "control codes"? What are you expecting a "control code" to manifest itself as in the output? If you are expecting it to literally be a string as in your question (`[Start C][FNC1]21417341123[Stop]`), then how would you distinguish between "control codes" and having the characters `[`, `S`, `t`, `a`, `r`, `t`, `]`, etc. in the barcode itself?

Comment: it's an OK question, just probably underspecified. What control codes, what have you tried, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare: [Start C] is a representation of 11010011100 in a code128 barcode.  In order to decode any bar code of the code128 spec, a reader would need to support control codes.  However, readers don't need to actually output the control codes.  I was hoping that there was a way that ZXing would do that natively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when people ask this question, they are talking about FNC codes in a format like Code 128. These don't  have a printable representation in the result, although FNC1 is translated as "]C1" or ASCII 29 as per the spec. The others really don't correspond to anything in the output, so don't result in any characters.

It looks like you're asking about a "START C" code. This too really isn't part of the string encoded by the barcode. It's an internal marker that tells it to switch sets for parsing the rest of the barcode.

Raw bytes make a bit more sense for other formats where there is clearly an underlying byte representation that is then further translated. For Code 128 it will give you all the (non-control) codes found in the barcode rather than the interpreted string. This is not what you want.

For your purpose you would have to modify the code. I think this only makes sense for some artificial use case  .

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Basically, I am trying to create an analyzer.  So every glyph (for lack of a better term) has to have a representation.  I understand that the vast majority of the time you wouldn't need to know that info, but it is of value to me to know.  For instance, I noticed that in Code128Reader, I see `switch (code) {
              case CODE_FNC_1:
                if (convertFNC1) {
                  if (result.length() == 0){
                    result.append("]C1");`.  But then later, it's deleted from result.  I may tweak it to still output.

Comment: That looks like old code... it outputs ASCII 29. https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/oned/Code128Reader.java Yes that makes sense and you can easily copy/change the code to do something on every symbol.

Comment: I seem to have found what I'm looking for.  It seems that I'll need to edit some readers.  To keep in your (ZXing's) good graces - if I publish this app, I need to redistribute my edited code, correct?  Thanks again for the project and your answers.

Comment: You can redistribute derivate works, sure. It's just covered by the Apache License 2.0. https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/LicenseQuestions

Answer (score 0):

The raw bytes returned in the result are the code word indices. What character or control code a code word means depends on what code set is active.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128

But since the start code is missing, the buffer is practically useless. I've modified it to include the start character to suit my purposes.

Comment: Since asking the question, I modified the Code128Reader class and the result class to accommodate a new class variable/parameter called analysis.  This will output all of the control codes that I'm looking for.  I'll share when complete, but I have a long way to go (I want to do the same for other readers).

Comment: Hi Tim, I wonder if you succeeded in adapting the code for outputting the control codes. This is for Android right?